# jQuery toggling an animation (with an image too)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, onclick, toggle

I want to toggle two separate properties on a click event:

1) An image within a div - toggling the `src` attribute

2) The absolute positioning of the div - toggling the `animate("top":"0px")` bit

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="emailme">
   <a id="email" href="mailto:xxx@gmail.com">xxx@gmail.com</a>
   <div id="emailmecopy">email me</div>
   <img id="emaildown"src="images/downbutton.png">
</div>
```

Now I've sorted the src toggling, but can't work out how to toggle the animation bit:

```
$("#emailme img").on({
      'click': function() {
        var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'images/downbutton.png')
              ? 'images/upbutton.png'
              : 'images/downbutton.png';
            $(this).attr('src', src);   //THIS TOGGLES THE IMAGE SRC

            //BUT WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO TOGGLE ANIMATE BETWEEN ("top":"0px") and 
            //("top":"-50px") IN THE SAME CLICK??

                     }
});
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($("#emailme img").css('top') == '0px'){
  $("#emailme img").stop().animate({top:'-50px'},1000);
};
if($("#emailme img").css('top') == '-50px'){
  $("#emailme img").stop().animate({top:'0px'},1000);
};
```

also check this out:

```
$('body').on('click', '#emailme img', function (e){
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src')=='images/downbutton.png'?'images/upbutton.png':'images/downbutton.png');
  if($(this).css('top') == '0px'){
    $(this).stop().animate({top:'-50px'},1000);
  };
  if($(this).css('top') == '-50px'){
    $(this).stop().animate({top:'0pg'},1000);
  };
});
```

Comment: Great... this is doing toggling the animation, thanks... however, the image src toggle is now not working, having put your code underneath it!

Comment: Scratch that, I had some old code tampering with it. Solved! Big thanks, much appreciated.... been staring at it for ages!

Comment: I'm glad to help you and I'm having fun at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor your code a bit you can do it like this. I suppose this is what you were looking for...

```
$("#emailme img").on({
  'click': function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var src = $this.attr('src');
    var isUp = src === 'images/upbutton.png';
    var newSrc = 'images/'+ (isUp ? 'downbutton' : 'upbutton') +'.png';

    $this.attr('src', newSrc)
      .animate({ top: (isUp ? '-50' : '0') +'px' });

  }
});
```